# Finding the max value of an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I've searched around for an answer but haven't had much luck trying to get the following to work.

I am currently taking a introductory programming class and have been faced with a exercise where I need to write two functions (i.e. a method that returns a value) that

a) Returns the maximum value and
b) The median value, from an array of double values.

Below is the code of where I am up to. I have successfully created a method that allows the user to input the the number of elements of the array and initialize them with a value. I am however having difficulty getting the method for calculating the maximum to work. I've explicitly been told to use the Math.max method. However whenever I try to run the code, I get the following error message after the user has initialized the array:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method max(double, double) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (double, double[])"
```

From what I have read in the API `Math.max` can handle double types. I'm a little clueless as to how to fix this. I have a feeling I need to create a loop, but I was under the impression the `foreach` loop is equivalent.

All responses will be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.gc01.lab2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class exercise22 {

    private static double [] numberInput(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers are in the array?");
        int count = input.nextInt();
        double [] array = new double [count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i + ": ");
            array [i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        return array;
    }

    private double  maximum (double [] array){
        double max = 0.0;
        for (double value : array){
            max = Math.max(0.0, array);
        }
        return  max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final exercise22 object = new exercise22 ();
        System.out.println("The maximum number inputted is " +
                object.maximum(object.numberInput()));

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `double` and `double[]`?

Comment: Don't pass in an array, pass in two doubles. Like `max` and `value`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently passing the entire array to Math.max() instead of just the value. To fix this, change `max = Math.max(0.0, array);` to `max = Math.max(0.0, value);`.

Further, you would always be comparing it to 0.0. You should set max to 0.0 before looping over the elements, and then do `max = Math.max(max, value);` so that it is compared with the current maximum.

Comment: Better use `Math.max(max, value)`

Comment: Thank you very much TF Nelson, this is perfect and works flawlessly! I understand the logic also!